Circular references error returning data based upon dropdown list selection
I have a summary sheet where I have a dropdown in C13 {"green";"brown"}.

If I select "Green", I want the formula to return 'Green Park'!A10:DD21
If I select "Brown", it should return 'Green Park'!A10:DD74

I tried to use the following formula but it doesn't work returning errors about circular references:
=IF(C13="Green",
   INDEX('Green Park'!A$10:DD$21, ROW(A1)), 
   IF(C13="Brown", INDEX('Green Park'!A$10:DD$74, ROW(A1)), ""))

Link to my example spreadsheet

Exact copy of Filter my daya based upon drop down list. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

=IF(COUNTIF({"Green","Brown"},C13),
   QUERY('Green Park'!A10:DD74, IF(C13="Green","Limit 21",)),)

COUNTIF  IF  QUERY

COUNTIF checks that there is a valid value in the dropdown, and if not, returns an empty value.
QUERY uses 'Green Park'!A10:DD74 as the range and if C13="Green" then the results are limited to 21 rows.

